# Cannot import class from module (circular reference issue?)

Tags: python, jupyter

I've seen countless issues here on stack about this but still can't figure out why I cant get mine to work. I have a 2 .ipynb files and I'm looking to import a class from one file to the other as follows:

CV_Screening_Interface:

```
from joblib import dump, load
import sys
import pandas as pd
import os
import import_ipynb
import docx
import readDocx ***(This is another ipynb file)***
from docx import Document
import string
model = load('model.joblib') 

    class CV:

        def __init__(self,university,major,masters,company,certification,GPA):
            self.university = university
            self.major = major
            self.masters = masters
            self.company = company
            self.certification = certification
            self.GPA = GPA

    #And a bunch of other functions
```

Now in FirstProgram

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import filedialog
from docx import Document
import io
import import_ipynb
import CV_Screening_Interface


#Till here works fine
```

When I try to import class CV I get an import error

```
from CV_Screening_Interface import CV 

OR

test = CV_Screening_Interface.CV()
```

ImportError: cannot import name 'CV' from 'CV_Screening_Interface' (CV_Screening_Interface.ipynb)

I checked PYTHONPATH, I have an empty **init**.py in the directory already. What's weird is that importing the module works, but importing the class in the module doesn't.

Note in CV_Screening_Interface CV class works perfectly fine so I don't think there is any issue with it specifically. Probably need a if **name**="**main**" inside it?

Comment: The indentation in the code for 'CV_Screening_Interface' is wrong.  Is this just an error introduced by copying and pasting to Stack Overflow?

Comment: Yes it is an issue due to copying and pasting. Class CV works perfectly fine inside the CV_Screening_Interface module.

Answer (score 0):

Ok so this solved my problems:

I created a new ipynb called ClassFile.ipynb and it only contains the Class CV without importing any packages

Then i converted ClassFile.ipynb to ClassFile.py and imported it to FirstProgram and it worked.